# Convert my program into a math formula

Tags: javascript, math, converters

So all started when I saw this numerical sequence onto a reddit post:

```
0 1 3 4 6 8 9 10 12 14 16 18 19 20 21 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 96 98 100 102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120 122 124 126 128 130 132 134 136 138 140 142 144 146 148 150 152 154 156 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 192 194 196 198 200 202 204 206 208 210 212 214 216 218 220 222 224 226 228 230 232 234 236 238 240 242 244 246 248 250 252 254 256 258 260 262 264 266 268 270 272 274 276 278 280 282 284 286 288 290 292 294 296 298 300 302 304 306 308 310 312 314 316 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 384 386 388 390 392 394 396 398 400 402 404 406 408 410 412 414 416 418 420 422 424 426 428 430 432 434 436 438 440 442 444 446 448 450 452 454 456 458 460 462 464 466 468 470 472 474 476 478 480 482 484 486 488 490 492 494 496 498 500 502 504 506 508 510 512 514 516 518 520 522 524 526 528 530 532 534 536 538 540 542 544 546 548 550 552 554 556 558 560 562 564 566 568 570 572 574 576 578 580 582 584 586 588 590 592 594 596 598 600 602 604 606 608 610 612 614 616 618 620 622 624 626 628 630 632 634 636 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753
```

And as the author pointed out:

> If you ignore the 0, I figured that it starts adding 2 one time, then 1 one time then 2 two times, 1 two times... 2 2n times, 1 2n times.

That's why I thought it's pretty easy thinking of a program that will return element n of the numerical sequence. So I came up with the following code (in javascript):

```js
function pot(x, y){
    if(y == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return pot(x, --y) * x;
    }
}

function f2(x){
    var n = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var progCount = 0;
    var sw = true;
    var current = 1;
    
    while(progCount < x){
        if(sw){
            current += 2;
        }else{
            current += 1;
        }
        
        count++;
        
        if(pot(2,n) == count){
            if(!sw){
                n++;
            }
            sw = !sw;
            count = 0;
        }
        
        progCount++;
    }
    
    return current;
}
```

However I still wasn't able to convert this into a math formula... What made me think a lot. Something in my head tells me there has to be a way to convert such basic programs into a math formula.

That's why I came here to ask the following 2 questions:

- 1) Do you know a way to create a math formula for the numerical
  sequence?
- 2) Is there a generic way to create a formula by a given
  code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to determine mathematically?

Comment: Are you asking a code question or a maths question?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying to detirmine a function f(n):N->N with the outputs of the numerical sequence.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess it's somewhere inbetween since I want to create a formula by analysing code, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you, but:

```
function fun(n) {
    var result, geo;
    geo = result = parseInt(Math.log(n + 1) / Math.log(2), 10);
    result = ((Math.pow(2, geo) - 2) / 2) * 3;


    var diff = n - (Math.pow(2, geo) - 1);
    geo = Math.pow(2, geo - 1);

    result += (diff >= geo) ? geo * 2 + (diff - geo) : diff * 2;
    return result + 1;
 }

var result = "";
for(var i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
     result += fun(i) + ", ";
}
console.log(result);
```

Tested it up to n = 100.

Comment: Sorry this code is kind of too hardcore for me the newbe. Can you explain the `geo = result = parseInt(Math.log(n + 1) / Math.log(2), 10);` line? I don't understand what `,10` does. And I'm completely failing at trying to understand `result += (diff >= geo) ? geo * 2 + (diff - geo) : diff * 2;`.

Comment: `parseInt()` takes two parameters: value to parse and radix, `, 10` means that we use decimal system.

Comment: Second thing you ask is short if
It is equivalent to:
if (diff >= geo) { result += geo * 2 + (diff - geo); } else { result += diff * 2; }
I see there is even better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this function for calculating any value.

```
function f(n) {
    function pow2(n) { return Math.pow(2, n); }

    var t = Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)),
        delta = n - pow2(t);

    return n < 2 ? n : pow2(t) + n - (delta < pow2(t - 1) ? pow2(t - 1) - delta : 1);
}
```

```js
function f(n) {
    function pow2(n) { return Math.pow(2, n); }

    var t = Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)),
        delta = n - pow2(t);

    return n < 2 ? n : pow2(t) + n - (delta < pow2(t - 1) ? pow2(t - 1) - delta : 1);
}

var i;

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    document.getElementById('tt').appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + ': ' + f(i) + '\n'));
}
```

```html
<pre id="tt"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+/g` to get all numbers as an array, `Array.prototype.reduceRight()`, `Array.prototype.unshift()`, `Array.prototype.reduce()`; mathematically use addition, subtraction to determine sequence of difference between numbers, and rebuild the original set from the sequence derived from original set.

```
let pattern = `0 1 3 4 6 8 9 10 12 14 16 18 19 20 21 22 24 26 28 30 32 
               34 36 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 
               64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
               90 91 92 93 94 96 98 100 102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 
               118 120 122 124 126 128 130 132 134 136 138 140 142 144 
               146 148 150 152 154 156 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 
               166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 
               180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 192 194 196 
               198 200 202 204 206 208 210 212 214 216 218 220 222 224 
               226 228 230 232 234 236 238 240 242 244 246 248 250 252 
               254 256 258 260 262 264 266 268 270 272 274 276 278 280 
               282 284 286 288 290 292 294 296 298 300 302 304 306 308 
               310 312 314 316 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 
               328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 
               342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 
               356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 
               370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 384 
               386 388 390 392 394 396 398 400 402 404 406 408 410 412 
               414 416 418 420 422 424 426 428 430 432 434 436 438 440 
               442 444 446 448 450 452 454 456 458 460 462 464 466 468 
               470 472 474 476 478 480 482 484 486 488 490 492 494 496 
               498 500 502 504 506 508 510 512 514 516 518 520 522 524 
               526 528 530 532 534 536 538 540 542 544 546 548 550 552 
               554 556 558 560 562 564 566 568 570 572 574 576 578 580 
               582 584 586 588 590 592 594 596 598 600 602 604 606 608 
               610 612 614 616 618 620 622 624 626 628 630 632 634 636 
               638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 
               652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 
               666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 
               680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 
               694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 
               708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 
               722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 
               736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 
               750 751 752 753`;

let arr = pattern.match(/\d+/g);

let sequence = [];

let first = arr.reduceRight((a, b) => {sequence.unshift(a-b); return b});

sequence.unshift(+first);

console.log(sequence);

let rebuild = [sequence[0]];

sequence.reduce((a, b) => {rebuild.push(a+b); return rebuild[rebuild.length-1]});

console.log(rebuild);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DrVDjDTOTNzCJ0sSEk3q?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

when I analyze the results the following applies:

- when n is power of 2, the result is always equal to n*1.5
- when n is power of 2, result of next n are added with 2 with maximum of the difference of result-n-1, eg. result of n=8 equals 12 and 8 is power of 2, in this case the following n => result are 8=>12, 9 => 14, 10 => 16, 12 => 18. The other values until next n is equal power are added with 1

Because of this formula will be like as follow:

```
Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(n)))*1.5+n%Math.pow(2,Math.floor(Math.log2(n))) + (n<Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(n)))*1.5-1 ? x-Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(n))) : Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(n)))*0.5-1)
```

or as function:

```
var fn = function (n) {
    var r0 = Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(n)));
    var r1 = r0 * 1.5 + n % r0;
    var r2 = n < r0 * 1.5 - 1 ? n - r0 : r0 * .5 - 1;
    return r1 + r2;
}
```

following loop will show the same result as numerical sequence

```
for (i = 1; i < 499; i++) {
    console.log(fn(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try polynomial interpolation

> In numerical analysis, polynomial interpolation is the interpolation of a given data set by a polynomial: given some points, find a polynomial which goes exactly through these points.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Try it out with wolframalpha

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+(1,1)+(2,3)+(3,4)+(4,6)+(5,8)+(6,9)+(7,10)+(8,12)+(9,14)+(10,16)

[image]

It gives you this function ( just copy and paste in javascript, it gaves you the solution between x[1,10] )

```
f(x) = -x^9/60480+(37 x^8)/40320-(107 x^7)/5040+(767 x^6)/2880-(5677 x^5)/2880+(50539 x^4)/5760-(693913 x^3)/30240+(110741 x^2)/3360-(5897 x)/280+5
```

x is the position of your list
f(x) is your solution

f(1) = 1
f(2) = 3
f(3) = 4
..
f(10) = 16

f(x>10) = is probably crap, because there are no known data points

Greetings

Comment: But I want one works with an unlimited amount of integers. Also I don't need the spaces in between the integers. Is there some way to get a better solution with Wolfram then? I don't actually know the programm